# Periodicity of a sum of periodic functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, periodic-functions

> The sum of two periodic functions is periodic if:
>
> a) Both periodic functions are continuous
> b) If the ratio of their fundamental periods is rational

Can someone explain why the first condition (continuity) is necessary? Thanks

Comment: It's not necessary. Completely irrelevant, in fact.

Comment: @Fundamental My prof specifically mentioned continuity. I asked him why and he said if continuity doesn't hold the theorem fails for some pretty weird cases.

Comment: @sgsdfg It were very interesting to see one.

Comment: Certainly (b) alone implies periodicity of the sum. Maybe he was asking about the reverse implication?